# How overwrite Django Admin readonly FileFields HREF url

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a `Django` project in production on `Apache` and I've made a model with file that is uploaded to custom path. Now I need to change it's representation in `Django` admin details. My `FileField` in admin is `readonly` and I want that it only shows a correct link to open the file in a new tab.

The problem is that I have alias in `Apache` and the current link showed in the admin is for example:

```
/var/www/html/moeaforhdl/moeaforhdlweb/uploads/uploaded_c_files/194/extracted_dfg.json
```

Screenshot:

[image]

But when I click to open the file it tries to open this URL:

```
http://201.174.122.25/moeaforhdlweb/uploads/var/www/html/moeaforhdl/moeaforhdlweb/uploads/uploaded_c_files/194/extracted_dfg.json
```

when the correct URL to open the file is:

```
http://201.174.122.25/moeaforhdlweb/uploads/uploaded_c_files/194/extracted_dfg.json
```

I need to remove this part when users click on the link in admin forms and details:

```
/var/www/html/moeaforhdl/moeaforhdlweb/uploads
```

How can I overwrite this URL in admin panel, por example in admin.py?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Check your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your `settings.py`

Comment: @dan-klasson estos son: MEDIA_URL = '/moeaforhdlweb/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '%s/moeaforhdlweb/uploads' % BASE_DIR

UPLOADS_FOLDER = '/moeaforhdlweb/uploads/'

Comment: Como sabias que hablo castellano? A ver, funciona en tu localhost?

Comment: @dan-klasson Gracias!!! todo me funciona bien respecto a la subida de ficheros, etc, lo que necesito es que un usuario desde el panel administrativo pueda pinchar en el link y abrir el archivo que fue subido en un nuevo tab, ahora mismo intenta abrir en un nuevo tab pero no lo encuentra porque esta parte de la URL sobra "/var/www/html/moeaforhdl/moeaforhdlweb/uploads". Entonces quisiera redefinir que para el panel administrativo esos links sean si esa parte de la URL.